# What should the return value of the websql sqlstatementerrorcallback be?

Tags: w3c, web-sql

https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#sqlstatementerrorcallback

See here that the sql statement error callback defines return type boolean :

```
[Callback=FunctionOnly, NoInterfaceObject]
interface SQLStatementErrorCallback {
  boolean handleEvent(in SQLTransaction transaction, in SQLError error);
};
```

Oppose that to

```
[Callback=FunctionOnly, NoInterfaceObject]
interface SQLTransactionErrorCallback {
  void handleEvent(in SQLError error);
};
```

Nowhere does it specify what the callback should return, and why it is a boolean.

many bindings, like the dart one for example ( https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-web_sql/SqlStatementErrorCallback.html ) have even defined it as void ( resulting in falsy? )

https://github.com/xpbrew/cordova-sqlite-storage/blob/dev/www/SQLitePlugin.js#L401 even throws an error if you do not return false.

I do realise it is a deprecated spec, but cordova chooses to be spec compliant here, so I need to be sure about how I interpret it.

Why is a statement error callback a boolean while transaction error callback for example is void ? What should I actually return in which scenario?

Comment: Have you figure out this question? I have same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I believe I ended up guessing, and I can't remember which way I guessed as I am no longer working on that project.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a possible answer here: [https://docs.kony.com](https://docs.kony.com/konylibrary/visualizer/viz_api_dev_guide/content/kony.db_functions.htm#SQLStatementErrorCallback)

`SQLStatementErrorCallback` returns a boolean value.

- `true` - ends the execution of the transaction. `true` is returned if there is no callback function specified as a parameter.
  Important: When `true` is returned, the transaction is rolled back.
- `false` - continues executing the transaction.

This way you can decide if you want to continue or roll back whole transaction.

As for `SQLTransactionErrorCallback`- there are no possible uses for return value.